# How to send pre DAO-Hardfork ETH safely?

Tags: transactions, wallets, hardforks, replay-attack

I have an Ethereum pre-fork (ETH/ETC) paper wallet which I'd like to send ETH out of.
I never touched it after the ETH/ETC fork so the same wallet holds the same amount in ETC as well.
To the best of my research, it shouldn't be a problem to send the ETH out, after EIP-155 was implemented (and replay attacks cannot happen anymore?? I hope..).

So my question, am I correct about the above and is there anything else I should be considering before moving pre-fork coins out?
Also, do I move the ETH out first (to an ETH wallet) and only then after the remaining ETC to a separate ETC wallet?

Thanks